# Stopping the ARM Cortex A8 CPU on Android device

Tags: android, arm, cpu

To improve battery performance we want to make the CPU clock stop/pause for little intervals when the device is not in use. Does anyone have any experience with doing this to the configuration mentioned in the subject of this post: ARM Cortex A8 CPU (a Archos 70 Internet  Tablet running Android)?

Any pointers on where to start?

Thanks.

Comment: Android automatically stops the CPU when the device is not in use.

Comment: It's not clear if you are trying to do this for the device as a whole or specifically in an app running on the device.  Trying to detect this yourself device-wide and control the CPU is troublesome more-so because the OS already does so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARM has the `WFE` and `WFI` instructions which cause the CPU to shut down until either an event (`SEV`) or an interrupt wakes the processor up. `WTE` is typically used by spin locks to prevent unnecessary CPU usage while `WFI` will be used by the kernel idle thread.

As other have said, this is not stuff that an application programmer should ever need to worry about. As an application programmer, all you really should be doing is suspending your thread until there is stuff for it to do. This will typically be done using `select`, `epoll` or waits on conditional_variables. Generally avoid sleep though.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an application's job to do that.

It just has to make sure that it doesn't do anything that the OS thinks is "work" (like spinning in a loop) when it should be "sleeping" using [Thread.sleep()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29), and let the OS deal with managing the CPU for power management purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Like CommonsWare points out, there's really no need for that. Android takes care of all CPU operations, and will slow down the CPU if there's nothing to do.